# Escape quotes is not working in spark 2.2.0 while reading csv

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to read my delimited file which is tab separated but not able to read all records.

Here is my input records:

```
head1   head2   head3
a   b   c
a2  a3  a4
a1  "b1 "c1
```

My code:

```
var inputDf = sparkSession.read
                  .option("delimiter","\t")
                  .option("header", "true")
//                  .option("inferSchema", "true")
                  .option("nullValue", "")
                  .option("escape","\"")
                  .option("multiLine", true)
                  .option("nullValue", null)
                  .option("nullValue", "NULL")
                  .schema(finalSchema)
                  .csv("file:///C:/Users/prhasija/Desktop/retriedAddresses_4.txt")
//                  .csv(inputPath)
                  .na.fill("")
//                  .repartition(4)

                  println(inputDf.count)
```

Output:

```
2 records
```

Why it is not returning 3 as count?

Comment: The last row is malformed.

Comment: whats the fix for this. I have to read this data with quotes

Comment: what does your finalSchema look like?

Comment: it is structType(Queue[StructField]()). all columns i have kept as string

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the following options to your read: .option("escape", "\\") and .option("quote", "\\")

```
val test = spark.read
    .option("header", true)
    .option("quote", "\\")
    .option("escape", "\\")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .csv(".../test.csv")
```

Here is the test csv I used it on:

```
a,b,c
1,b,a
5,d,e
5,"a,"f
```

Full output:

```
scala> val test = spark.read.option("header", true).option("quote", "\\").option("escape", "\\").option("delimiter", ",").csv("./test.csv")
test: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: string ... 1 more field]

scala> test.show
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  b|  a|
|  5|  d|  e|
|  5| "a| "f|
+---+---+---+


scala> test.count
res11: Long = 3
```