# Pyspark read csv doesn't read whole column when escape character is quote(")

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

If I have a quote(") as an escape character and read data using pyspark read API, it doesn't get mapped correctly.

Following is how one can reproduce it.

```
tx = 'id,name,address,city,country\n"1","",", 1ST, ""Round Street""","",UK'
file=open('temp.csv','wt')
file.writelines(tx)
file.close()
df = spark.read.csv('temp.csv', header=True, escape='"')

df.show(1,False)
+---+----+---------------------+----+-------+
|id |name|address              |city|country|
+---+----+---------------------+----+-------+
|1  |null|, 1ST, "Round Street"|null|UK     |
+---+----+---------------------+----+-------+

df.select('address').show(1, False)
+-------+
|address|
+-------+
| 1ST   |
+-------+
```

Am I missing something in this as I am not getting the correct column value?

Comment: I'm not I understand it correctly, but as I see you are able to read the data, but can't show the whole column. Can you try `df.show(20,False)`?

Comment: Or maybe `df.select('address').show(20,False)`

Comment: So df.show() is reading correctly. However, when I try to select just one column then it does get correct values. It just tries to read one column and doesn't get mapped to correct value

Comment: Maybe this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995878/escape-quotes-is-not-working-in-spark-2-2-0-while-reading-csv

Comment: Thanks @assaf , That scenario is different than the above. That scenario uses \ as escape char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with this setup

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

tx = '''id,name,address,city,country
"1","",", 1ST, ""Round Street""","",UK
"1"," ",", 1ST, ""Round Street""","",UK
"id-1","name-1",", 1ST, ""Round Street""","city-1",UK'''

with open('temp.csv','wt') as file:
    file.writelines(tx)

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("csv")\
  .option("sep", ",")\
  .option("quote", '"')\
  .option("escape", '"')\
  .option("inferSchema", "true")\
  .option("header", "true")\
  .load('temp.csv').rdd.toDF()

df.select('address').show()
df.show()
```

Run

```sh
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> 
>>> tx = '''id,name,address,city,country
... "1","",", 1ST, ""Round Street""","",UK
... "1"," ",", 1ST, ""Round Street""","",UK
... "id-1","name-1",", 1ST, ""Round Street""","city-1",UK'''
>>> 
>>> with open('temp.csv','wt') as file:
...     file.writelines(tx)
... 
>>> spark = SparkSession \
...     .builder \
...     .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
...     .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
...     .getOrCreate()
>>> 
>>> df = spark.read.format("csv")\
...   .option("sep", ",")\
...   .option("quote", '"')\
...   .option("escape", '"')\
...   .option("inferSchema", "true")\
...   .option("header", "true")\
...   .load('temp.csv').rdd.toDF()
>>>
>>>
>>> df.show()
+----+------+--------------------+------+-------+
|  id|  name|             address|  city|country|
+----+------+--------------------+------+-------+
|   1|  null|, 1ST, "Round Str...|  null|     UK|
|   1|      |, 1ST, "Round Str...|  null|     UK|
|id-1|name-1|, 1ST, "Round Str...|city-1|     UK|
+----+------+--------------------+------+-------+

>>> df.select('address').show()
+--------------------+
|             address|
+--------------------+
|, 1ST, "Round Str...|
|, 1ST, "Round Str...|
|, 1ST, "Round Str...|
+--------------------+
```

Test versions

```
Python 3.6.12
pyspark==3.0.1
spark==0.2.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This doesn't escape the quote(") within the data. As we can see in the screenshot, it has ""Round S.... Rather it should have been "Round S..

Comment: Can you provide more sample data? - the data is escaped, that is why it is there. With the escape character :)

Comment: Data is generated from a database and escape character for quote is used quote(") itself. And after reading we just need one quote in the data.

The expected output is `, 1ST, "Round Street"`

Comment: updated, but more data would have helped.

Comment: So this does work, so we have to convert to rdd and then convert back to DataFrame. Not ideal but it works. Thanks

Comment: Not ideal at all, but the python code has issue with the lazy execution and does not parse the text properly. This solution imo is acceptable tradeoff, and does not touch disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the `escape=` parameter not as intended.

```
escape – sets a single character used for escaping quotes inside an already quoted value. If None is set, it uses the default value, \.
```

Without `escape` you get the desired output.

Comment: I have edited the example. We need to use escape character to escape the quote. As seen in above example quote and escape character is same